# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find autoprefixer-rails-9.7.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add bootstrap to my rails application, but now when I run the app it show the following error:

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find autoprefixer-rails-9.7.3 in any of the sources
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
web_1  |   /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

This is how I added it to my **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
```

And this is my **Gemfile.lock** file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activeadmin (2.3.1)
      arbre (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.1)
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n (~> 0.4)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
      kaminari (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      ransack (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1)
      sprockets (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
      sprockets-es6 (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.2)
    activejob (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
    activerecord (5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    arbre (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    archive-zip (0.12.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    ast (2.4.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.7.3)
      execjs
    aws-eventstream (1.0.3)
    aws-partitions (1.228.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.72.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.228.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.25.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.71.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.51.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.71.0)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.1.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    babel-source (5.8.35)
    babel-transpiler (0.7.0)
      babel-source (>= 4.0, < 6)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bcrypt (3.1.13-java)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootsnap (1.4.5-java)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sassc (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.1)
    capybara (3.29.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (2.0.0)
      rake (< 13.0)
    chromedriver-helper (2.1.1)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.7.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.11.1)
    ffi (1.11.1-java)
    ffi (1.11.1-x64-mingw32)
    ffi (1.11.1-x86-mingw32)
    formtastic (3.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    has_scope (0.7.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1)
    i18n (1.6.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    inherited_resources (1.11.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 5.0, < 6.1)
      responders (>= 2, < 4)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.3)
    jaro_winkler (1.5.3-java)
    jbuilder (2.9.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    jquery-rails (4.3.5)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    kaminari (1.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.1.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.1.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.1.1)
    kaminari-core (1.1.1)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.3.1)
    msgpack (1.3.1-java)
    msgpack (1.3.1-x64-mingw32)
    msgpack (1.3.1-x86-mingw32)
    nio4r (2.5.1)
    nio4r (2.5.1-java)
    nokogiri (1.10.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    nokogiri (1.10.4-java)
    nokogiri (1.10.4-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    nokogiri (1.10.4-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    parallel (1.17.0)
    parser (2.6.4.1)
      ast (~> 2.4.0)
    pg (1.1.4)
    pg (1.1.4-x64-mingw32)
    pg (1.1.4-x86-mingw32)
    polyamorous (2.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    puma (3.12.1)
    puma (3.12.1-java)
    rack (2.0.7)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.3)
      actioncable (= 5.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      actionview (= 5.2.3)
      activejob (= 5.2.3)
      activemodel (= 5.2.3)
      activerecord (= 5.2.3)
      activestorage (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.2.0)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.3)
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)
      activesupport (= 5.2.3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (12.3.3)
    ransack (2.3.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (= 2.3.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (1.6.0)
    responders (3.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rubocop (0.74.0)
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5.1)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.6)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7)
    ruby-progressbar (1.10.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (1.2.3)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc (2.2.1-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc (2.2.1-x86-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.4)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 3.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.2)
    spring (2.1.0)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)
      babel-source (>= 5.8.11)
      babel-transpiler
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    thread_safe (0.3.6-java)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2019.3)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.1-java)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.4)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  java
  ruby
  x64-mingw32
  x86-mingw32
  x86-mswin32

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin
  aws-sdk-s3
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  devise (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.3)
  rubocop
  sass-rails
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.6p201

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3
```

I tried deleting the Gemfile.lock but it didn't work and I tried running bundle install --no-deployment and bundle install --path vendor/cache

Answer (score 0):

**Gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
```

**Should to be**

```
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'
    gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.1.0'
```